# How to search views with exposed filters

Tags: views, search

I have a page view with exposed filters (4 checkboxes with ajax calling) which user can change.

I want to change default search, to searching only results which appears in this view.

How can I do that?

Comment: Are you trying to filter a list of Views results using exposed filters?  I'm not understanding how you want to combine both... they're two separate things.  "Search" searchers for content on the whole site, and Exposed Filters simply allows users to filter a list of Views Results.

Comment: Hi all and thanks for quick reply.

I am getting views result and exposed filter works perfectly, it gave me good result. 

Next situation is: 
I want to add user an additional option to search this view, to search result which i am getting with exposed filters. 
I added search terms field in filter criteria, but when type something it searching only by title, and i wanted to search by title, body and location. These fields are already included my views.

Answer (score 2):

[Views filter populate](http://drupal.org/project/views_filters_populate) should help you with your issue.  What you need to do is don't expose the Title, Body, and Location in the Filter Criteria of your view.  Then add Populate filters and expose it and select Title, Body, and Location as your filters.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want your view to display results ONLY when one of the checkboxes is checked. Am I right ?

If it's the case, in your view's Exposed Form section, you have to choose `Input required` as the Exposed form style.

Comment: Hi all and thanks for quick reply.

I am getting views result and exposed filter works perfectly, it gave me good result. 

Next situation is: 
I want to add user an additional option to search this view, to search result which i am getting with exposed filters. 
I added search terms field in filter criteria, but when type something it searching only by title, and i wanted to search by title, body and location. These fields are already included my views.

Comment: Searching on several fields cannot be achieved without code. Besides, it's another topic and you should open a new question for it.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the *Global:Populate filters (exposed)* Under **Filter Criteria**, make sure your body and location are checked.

Also, make sure your **Operator** are set correctly. For instance, set your **Filter Criteria** to something like this:

- Content: Published (yes) AND
- Content: Type (= your content)
- AND

  - Content: Title (contains) OR
  - Content: body (contains) OR
  - Content: location (contains) OR
  - Global: Populate filters (exposed)